# Attribute *** has already been defined

Tags: android

I received the following error when running my android application.

```
/home/vaibhav/AndroidStudioProjects/appName/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml 
Error:(2) Attribute "headerLayout" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.com.android.ide.common.process.
ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command '/home/vaibhav/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

The problem is there is no attribute "headerLayout" in colors.xml file. And how can i find the duplicate instance of "headerLayout" definition ?

Edit: So i found out that there is already any attribute in generated R file named "headerLayout". It seems like I have two dependencies and both have the attribute "headerLayout". How do I remove the conflict ?

Comment: search for "headerLayout" in entire project by pressing `shift+shift`

Comment: check your colors.xml file headerLayout code

Comment: @Tauqir : i tried searching with shift+shift but couldn't find "headerLayout".

Comment: @sasikumar : i checked colors.xml , it does not contain "headerLayout"

Comment: try with clean and build?

Comment: or try invalidate cache /restart from file menu

Comment: try @Tauqir answer also  invalidate cache /restart from file menu

Comment: also check the projects referenced from your project.

Comment: i tried to invalidate cache/restart. it didn't work

Comment: @Tauqir : I found the attribute in R. How do I resolve the conflict ?

Comment: Its because you are using an old version of ExpandbleLayout Library. Check here:
https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout/issues/24

Answer (score 2):

```
Attribute "closeIcon" has already been defined
Attribute "iconTint" has already been defined
Attribute "icon" has already been defined
```

*Update your Android SDK Build Tool.*
Go to **Tools**->**Android**->**Android SDK Manager**->**Tools** Tab->
**Android SDK Build Tools**-> **select version**(27.0.3 for me) and **Apply change**.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. This is basically an android issue. Refer
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22576

You cannot have same attributes name even if they are coming from different libraries in your project. I had to change the attribute names in the library code.

Comment: how did you changed the attribute names

Comment: Brother, How to change those conflicting attribute names?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have problem with view_expandable_headerlayout.
headerLayout is duplicated with design library.
Open Atrrs.xml
then rename headerLayout to ex_headerLayout

```
<declare-styleable name="ExpandableLayout">
        <attr name="ex_headerLayout" format="reference" />
        <attr name="contentLayout" format="reference" />
        <attr name="duration" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

It will work.